# Spring integration service activator with multiple messages

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I would like to process multiple messages at a time e.g. get 10 messages from the channel at a time and write them to a log file at once.

Given the scenario, can I write a service activator which will get messages in predefined set i.e. 5 or 10 messages and process it? If this is not possible then how to achieve this using Spring Integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what you can get with the [Aggregator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator). You can collect several messages to the group using simple expression like `size() == 10`. When the group is complete, the `DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor` emits a single message with the list of payloads of messages in the group. The result you can send to the service-activator for handling the batch at once.

**UPDATE**

Something like this:

```
.aggregate(aggregator -> aggregator
                        .correlationStrategy(message -> 1)
                        .releaseStrategy(group -> group.size() == 10)
                        .outputProcessor(g -> new GenericMessage<Collection<Message<?>>>(g.getMessages()))
                        .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true))
```

So, we correlate messages (group or buffer them) by the static `1` key.
The group (or buffer size is `10`) and when we reach it we emit a single message which contains all the message from the group. After emitting the result we clean the store from this group to allow to form a new one for a fresh sequence of messages.

Comment: See an UDATE in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is creating the messages in the first place; if a message-driven channel adapter, the concurrency in that adapter is the key.

For other message sources, you can use an `ExecutorChannel` as the input channel to the service activator, with an executor with a pool size of 10.

Depending on what is sending messages, you need to be careful about losing messages in the event of a server failure.

It's difficult to provide a general answer without more information about your application.

Comment: ExecutorChannel will help to generate parallelism and get the messages in parallel but I would like to process them in bulk instead of one message at a time. Aggregator Channel might work but how to make sure every 5 or 10 message will be part of the same group so that they can be processed in bulk.

Comment: Yes, an aggregator after the service activator would work; with a simple release strategy (`size() == 10`).