# Why message are stuck at aggregator?

Tags: spring-integration

Messages are taking from 20 mins to and an hours sometimes to reach from splitter to aggregate.

I have aggregator to send the email messages to smtp in the batch. sometime, messages take long time to reach OmniAlertsEmailAdapter from OmniAlertsEmailSplitter.

```
<!-- Split message into separate email messages for delivery -->
<splitter id="omniAlertsEmailSplitter"
        input-channel="omniAlertsEmailDeliveryChannel"
        output-channel="omniAlertsEmailDeliveryProcessChannel" method="split">
        <beans:bean class="com.omnialerts.splitter.OmniAlertsEmailSplitter"> </beans:bean>
</splitter>

<!-- 
    the poller will process 1000 messages every second 
    if the size of the group is 1000 (the poll reached the max messages) or 1 seconds time out (poll has less than 1000 messages) then the payload with the list of messages is passed to defined output channel
-->
<aggregator input-channel="omniAlertsEmailDeliveryProcessChannel" output-channel="omniAlertsEmailDispatchChannel"
    discard-channel="omniAlertsEmailDispatchChannel"

    send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
    group-timeout="1000"
    correlation-strategy-expression="T(Thread).currentThread().id"
    release-strategy-expression="size() == 1000">
    <poller max-messages-per-poll="1000" fixed-rate="1000"/>
</aggregator>
<channel id="omniAlertsEmailDeliveryProcessChannel">
     <queue/>
</channel>
<service-activator
        input-channel="omniAlertsEmailDispatchChannel"
        output-channel="omniAlertsEmailDeliveryStatusChannel" method="send">

        <beans:bean class="com.omnialerts.adapters.OmniAlertsEmailAdapter"> </beans:bean>
</service-activator>
<channel id="omniAlertsEmailDeliveryStatusChannel" />
```

It works fine mostly, but on some JVMs I notice this delay. might be due to some extra load on those JVMs but it should not take more then few seconds.
Am I missing something in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You try to rely on the `TaskScheduler` with `10` threads in its poll. These threads can be used in other processes, so your aggregator might not have so much attraction.

I'm not sure what is the point to split and aggregate immediately, but you may consider to use a dedicated `task-executor` for that `<poller>`, so all the aggregator tasks are going to be executed in its own thread pool.

Consider also to use an:

```
 <xsd:attribute name="expire-groups-upon-completion" default="false">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>
                        Boolean flag specifying if MessageGroup should be removed once completed. Useful for
                        handling late arrival use cases where messages arriving with the correlationKey that
                        is the same as the completed MessageGroup will be discarded. Default is 'false'
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:boolean xsd:string" />
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:attribute>
```

Instead of `discard-channel`.

Comment: I used splitter and aggregator because I need to send a batch of 1000 messages to SMTP. Is there a better option?

Comment: QueueChannel with maxMessagesPerPoll = 1000 on the poller, but you still need an Aggregator afterwards based on the thread id for correlation and some trigger to release not full groups. The advice on the poller can do that, though, but doesn’t look like that solution is simpler. The new `FluxAggregatorMessageHandler` should be better fit for this task: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.RC1/reference/html/aggregator.html#flux-aggregator

Comment: I followed your(@artem-bilan) suggestion, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737672/spring-integration-service-activator-with-multiple-messages

Comment: Right, but there was no story about messages stuck. And it really doesn’t matter what component you use if threads for processing your tasks are busy